# Theorem: Let $f$ be defined on $[a,b]$. If $f$ is differentiable at a point $x \in [a,b]$, then $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Tags: real-analysis

> > Theorem: Let $f$ be defined on $[a,b]$. If $f$ is differentiable at a point $\in [a,b]$, then $f$ is continuous at $x$.
> >
> > Proof: As $t \to x$, we have, by theorem 4.4, 
> >     $$f(t) - f(x) = \frac{f(t)-f(x)}{(t-x)} (t-x)  \to f'(x)\cdot 0 = 0.$$

Could you help me understand how Theorem 4.4 is related to this proof?

> **$\mathbf{4.4}\,\,\,$ Theorem$\quad$** *Suppose $E\subset X$, a metric space, $p$ is a limit point of $E$, $f$ and $g$ are complex functions on $E$, and $$\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=A,\quad\lim_{x\to p}g(x)=B.$$ Then*
>
> $\begin{align}\text{(a)}&\lim_{x\to p}(f+g)(x)=A+B;\\
> \text{(b)}&\lim_{x\to p}(fg)(x)=AB;\\
> \text{(c)}&\lim_{x\to p}\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)(x)=\frac{A}{B}, \text{ if }B\ne 0.\\
> \end{align}$

Comment: why do you expect them to be related?

Comment: @IttayWeiss: because the proof relies on Theorem 4.4. When this happens, the theorem invoked has better be related to what is proven.

Comment: I thought you meant how are the two related in a very broad sense. You actually meant "where is Theorem 4.4 used in the proof of the above theorem" I guess. In any case, the first equality in the proof you mention is incorrect, so something is wrong. As for the use of Theorem 4.4, you have there a limit involving a sum and a quotient. So, Theorem 4.4 a and c are used. But again, the proof you quote is wrong.

Comment: @Ittay Weiss I think someone edited and erased (t-x).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $F(t)\stackrel{\rm{}def}{=}\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}$, $G(t)\stackrel{\rm{}def}{=}t-x$, and apply Theorem 4.4 (b) on $F$, $G$ with limit point $p \stackrel{\rm{}def}{=} x$.

Since $F$ is differentiable at $p$, $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to p} F(t)=f^\prime(x)\stackrel{\rm{}def}{=} A$; while clearly $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to p} G(t)=0 \stackrel{\rm{}def}{=} B$.